# swift how to push back to navigation view control

Tags: ios, swift, embed, navigationbar, tabbar

I have several view controllers and they are very complexed.

- MainVC (embed with tab bar controller)

  - FriendListVC
  - ChatRoomUpperVC (embed with navigation view controller)
  - ChatRoomVC (NavigationViewController with embed in ChatRoomUpperVC) (only shows the tab bar)

    - ChatRoomQuestionVC (pushed from ChatRoomVC) (only shows the navigation bar)
    - MatchedWaitVC (pushed from ChatRoomQuestionVC) (hide both tab and navigation bars)

      - ChatVC (pushed from MatchedWaitVC) (only shows the navigation bar)
  - SettingVC

What I have to do is when I click the back button from the ChatVC, I should back to ChatRoomVC and show the tab bar on the bottom only.

I tried the code below but it shows the black screen and there is no tar bar neither.

```
    override func willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
        if parent == nil
        {
            var viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers
            viewControllers?.removeLast(3)
            navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers!, animated: true)
            self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use following hack to achieve what you want. In the `viewDidLoad` method of the `ChatVC` do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let root = navigationController?.viewControllers.first {
        navigationController?.viewControllers = [root, self]
    }
}
```

This will remove the inbetween view controllers that are between `ChatVC` and `ChatRoomVC`. Now popping back (e.g. using the standard back button, or swiping from the left edge of the screen) will jump back directly to the `ChatRoomVC`.

**EDIT**

To show the tabBar again in the `ChatRoomVC`, add this to the `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

This will ensure that as soon as `ChatRoomVC` appears on the screen, its tabBar will be presented, too.

Comment: Could you please help me how can I show the tab bar when I get back to the roof navigation controller?